# Calculating bounded area by double integral

Tags: integration

It is the first time i see an integral that i need to calculate and it defined that way. Can somebody give me the way or a hint how I solve it ?

I have to calculate the area that bounded by $(3x + 4y + 7)^2 + (2x + y + 3)^2 = 1 $  using $\int \int $.

Comment: Expand the square, collect like terms, complete the square, etc. until you get to something of the form $c(x-a)^2 + d(y-b)^2 = e$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $u=3x+4y$ and $v=2x+y$ your domain transforms to $(u+7)^2+(v+3)^2=1$, a circle of area $\pi$. Since the transformation is linear, the area of your domain is given by the absolute value of
$$
\frac{\pi}{\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 4\\ 2 & 1\end{vmatrix}}=\frac{\pi}{3\cdot 1-4\cdot 2}=-\frac{\pi}{5},
$$
i.e. the area is $\pi/5$. You could also bookkeep the calculation with integrals,
$$
\int_{D_{xy}}1\,dx\,dy = \int_{D_{uv}}1\cdot \frac{d(x,y)}{d(u,v)}\,du\,dv=\int_{D_{uv}}\frac{1}{\frac{d(u,v)}{d(x,y)}}\,du\,dv=\int_{D_{uv}}\frac{1}{\text{abs}\,\biggl(\begin{vmatrix} 3 & 4\\ 2 & 1\end{vmatrix}\biggr)}\,du\,dv=\frac{\pi}{5}.
$$

Comment: Your substitution transforms the curve to $(u+7)^2+v+3=1$. You seem to have added a square to the second term in parentheses, which isn't there in the OP's question as written. However, I suspect the typo is his and that it really should be squared.

Comment: Thank you @DavidH! I leave the answer as is for the moment to get a reaction from OP. That was indeed sloppy of me!

Comment: The other commenter apparently did the same thing. ;)

Comment: No, the other one seem to say "Expand the square" and not "Expand the squares". The mistake is completely mine, it seems...

Comment: Ops, of course it should be squared )

Comment: but with the circle, dont i have to do a moved (from the center) polar substitution ?

Comment: I guess that if you know what the area of a circle is, you don't. Ask your teacher what is required...